# Python | String check case insensitive

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, search, discord

I am working on something that will post the link to the suicide prevention website if it detects a keyword inside a message (string).

`Example message: I want to just hang myself`

The program will detect the "hang myself" and will post the link

Right now the program is only able to search for the keywords when the user types exactly with the case, for example, "Suicide" will not register but "suicide" will

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):    
    suicide = ['kill myself', 'kill me'...]    
    for word in suicide:
        if message.content.count(word) > 0:
            *send message to the suicide prevention website*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The python function `lower()` converts all case-based characters in a string to lowercase and returns it.

```
if message.content.lower().count(word) > 0:
    #execute code
```